# Columns from mutiple tables in ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY .... ORDER BY ...)

Tags: sql, common-table-expression, netezza

I am using the `ROW_NUMBER` function like this

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TABLE1.COL1, TABLE2.COL1 ORDER BY TABLE1.COL4) as ROWNUM
FROM TABLE1
JOIN TABLE2
ON ......
```

The data that I am running this query with returns only one row but the ROWNUM is not 1 as I expect, sometimes it is 4 and sometimes 5.

Is it wrong to use columns from mutiple tables in the `PARTITION BY... ORDER BY..`

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 2):

The `partition by` will restart the row count for each change in Table1.col1 and Table2.col1

It seems like you are expecting a result which would be achieved through the following change:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TABLE1.COL4) as ROWNUM
FROM TABLE1
JOIN TABLE2
ON ......
```